# What word would you use to describe if you are fascinated but feeling inferior/doubting yourself at the same time?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, vocabulary

I was feeling unsure if I should do this undergrad research opportunity given to me. The professor sent me some research papers to look and, I can definitely say I am interested now, but I'm also heavily doubting my ability to contribute anything of value to the research.

What word would I describe myself right now? Fascinated but doubtful of my abilities at the same time?

Maybe even fascinated and scared at the same time. Like if I was in an adventure movie and the scenery was amazing but I was scared if I could make it through the dangerous landscape, but I was still fascinated with how it looked before I start my adventure. IDK. something like that

Comment: Welcome!  I would go with *Newly invigorated* but at least *Hooked*. You have new motivation for the project that was not there before. Also, rest assured that the you are not qualified to know the end value of your contribution. You simply have to pitch in and see where it goes.

Comment: You suffer from the anti-Dunning-Kruger effect.

Comment: Thanks for all these ideas! these are amazing I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **frisson** would sum up the state you are in pretty nicely.

> a brief moment of emotional excitement : SHUDDER, THRILL

*produce a genuine frisson of disquiet*
— Patricia Craig

*a frisson of surprise*

*a frisson of delight*

[Merriam-Webster]

OR

**have/get/feel butterflies in your stomach**

> to feel very nervous or excited about something that you have to do, especially something important

*Do you get butterflies when you have to talk to lots of people*?

[Macmillan]

Comment: awesome stuff, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I really like @user405662's "frisson", but two words I keep coming back to are *solicitude* and *trepidation*.

> *solicitude*: 1(a): the state of being concerned and anxious
> (b): attentive care and protectiveness 2. a cause of care or concern —usually used in plural. ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solicitude))

> *trepidation*: a nervous or fearful feeling of uncertain agitation : APPREHENSION ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trepidation))

I can't really decide between the two, but I like solicitude because it lacks some of the darkness associated with trepidation.

Comment: love the words! thanks for the suggestions